# plotting stl with time series data

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to use stl to get a breakdown of the seasonal and trend in my timeseries data. I have tick data, and I have created a ts object.

I ran a SQL query to get the data in the below form

```
    > x
         datetime       price
1  2010-09-08 1501        9110
2  2010-09-08 1501        9110
3  2010-09-08 1501        9110
4  2010-09-08 1501        9110
5  2010-09-08 1501        9115
6  2010-09-08 1501        9115
7  2010-09-08 1501        9110
8  2010-09-08 1502        9115
9  2010-09-08 1502        9115
10 2010-09-08 1502        9115
11 2010-09-08 1503        9120
12 2010-09-08 1503        9115
13 2010-09-08 1503        9115
14 2010-09-08 1503        9115
15 2010-09-08 1503        9115
16 2010-09-08 1503        9115
17 2010-09-08 1503        9115
18 2010-09-08 1503        9115
19 2010-09-08 1503        9115
20 2010-09-08 1503        9115
21 2010-09-08 1503        9115
22 2010-09-08 1503        9110
23 2010-09-08 1503        9105
24 2010-09-08 1503        9105
25 2010-09-08 1503        9110
26 2010-09-08 1504        9110
27 2010-09-08 1504        9110
28 2010-09-08 1504        9110
29 2010-09-08 1504        9110
30 2010-09-08 1504        9115
31 2010-09-08 1504        9115
32 2010-09-08 1504        9115
33 2010-09-08 1504        9115
34 2010-09-08 1504        9115
35 2010-09-08 1504        9115
36 2010-09-08 1504        9115
37 2010-09-08 1504        9120
```

and I converted it into ts by running the following:

```
> xt<-ts(x[,2])
> xt
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 37 
Frequency = 1 
 [1] 9110 9110 9110 9110 9115 9115 9110 9115 9115 9115 9120 9115 9115 9115 9115
[16] 9115 9115 9115 9115 9115 9115 9110 9105 9105 9110 9110 9110 9110 9110 9115
[31] 9115 9115 9115 9115 9115 9115 9120

> drg<-stl(log(xt),"per")
Error in stl(log(xt), "per") : 
  series is not periodic or has less than two periods

> is.ts(xt)
[1] TRUE
```

any suggestion on how I can fix the error, to be able to see the breakdown of the different trend components...

Comment: I haven't done much work with time-series, so just to clarify: is it the `plot` function producing the error or `stl`? i.e. if you do the `drg <- stl(...)` on its own line and then `plot(drg)`, which line throws the error? My guess is `plot`, so perhaps `drg` is not what you expect it to be. Can you provide a small sample of your data that reproduces your problem?

Comment: it is the stl portion `> drg<-stl(log(xt),"per")
Error in stl(log(xt), "per") : 
  series is not periodic or has less than two periods
` I'll update my post with a small sample of the data in just a few minutes

Comment: just updated post with small data sample that reproduces the problem

Comment: Please don't [cross post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-finance/attachments/20120116/ef480e8d/attachment.pl).  At minimum, have the courtesy to say you did, so others can benefit.

Answer (score 11):

The error is right there for you to see

```
 > drg<-stl(log(xt),"per")
 Error in stl(log(xt), "per") : 
   series is not periodic or has less than two periods
```

The `stl()` function need both a timeseries object *and* a frequency (or equally, increment) so the *seasonal* part makes any sense.  For longer-dated macro-economic series, it is usually 1/12 for monthly, or 1/4 for quarterly data.  See `help(ts)` for details, and look more closely at the examples for `ts()` and `stl()`, and the type of data used there.

Doing this with business-daily data is ... harder as the calendar is, well, irregular.   With your intra-daily data, you have to come up with some scheme.  Such data is fundamentally different: markets open and close, whereas the macro data can be conceptualized as being continuous.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, I appreciate the reasoning and your clarification. With your expertise, would you have any suggestion on a potential scheme, perhaps that can be applied on weekly OHLC data. Or is there another function that you would suggest using for similar type of analysis on stock prices

Comment: @itcplpl try with the *zoo* or *xts* package to create a series in their formats, then coerce to `ts` object using their `as.ts()` methods. Other than that, model the seasonal and trend components directly using an additive model - I did something similar recently using the mgcv package which has cyclic smoothers for the weekly effect. Far more involved that STL but well worth the effort that canned techniques like STL can match